# vuejs not updating after axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

Template:

`<h5>{{ this.phonelist.length }}</h5>` // originally `1`, after axios call should be `2`

Script:

```js
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      phonelist: [
        {
          name: "test"
        }
      ]
    },
    
    methods: {
    auth() {
      var self = this;
      // get token
      axios
        .post(
          "API_URL",
          {
            headers: {
              accept: "application/json"
            }
          }
        )
        .then(function(data) {
          const token = data.data.data.token;
          self.getList(token);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error", error);
        });
    },
    getList(token) {
      axios
        .get(GET_LIST_API, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + token
          }
        })
        .then(function(data) {
          const list = data.data.data;
          console.log(list); // [{name: "user1"}, {name: "user2"}]

          self.phonelist = list;
          console.log(self.phonelist);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error", error);
        });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.auth();
  }
};
```

the `console.log` shows the data is coming in with the right format, but on the frontend the data doesn't change. the `phonelist` is an array of objects.

Comment: did you also added an `key` attribute to your element that you want to render?

Comment: @Ifaruki tried that too, nothing changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `self` in `getList` but you haven't declared it inside that method.

Comment: @bboy did you take a look into the console too? it should throw you an error